# ! Misplaced \omit. \multispan ->\omit

Tags: multicolumn

I have tried to see if my error is the same as any of the numerous other threads on this forum with the same content, however I cannot seem to find any that match my problem.

When trying to typeset the following code, I am faced with a `! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit` error.

```
$$
\begin{array} {l r@{}l@{} r@{}l@{}}
\text{Max}  \quad   &   R   &{}\multicolumn{3}{l}{=\log\left(...............\right)}    \\
\text{s.t.} \quad   &   A   &{}=    B.C.D   &   E   &{}=    F.G.H   \\
                    &   I   &{}=    J.K.L   &   M   &{}=    N.O.P   \\
\end{array}
$$
```

My aim is to have it look like the following:

Max R=log(......)

s.t. A=B.C.D E=F.G.H

I=J.K.L M=N.O.P

where R, A and I are vertically aligned, as are E and M but they are aligned under the contents of the log to save space.

I am presuming the error is due to the alignment tabs and the multicolumn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{}` group should go *inside* the `\multicolumn`; you're forgetting `@{}` too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array} {l r@{}l@{} r@{}l@{}}
\text{Max}  \quad   &   R   &\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{{}=\log\left(...............\right)}    \\
\text{s.t.} \quad   &   A   &{}=    B.C.D   &   E   &{}=    F.G.H   \\
                    &   I   &{}=    J.K.L   &   M   &{}=    N.O.P   \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503) for reasons why `$$` should never be used in LaTeX.

[image]

A different trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\multialign}[2]{%
  \multispan{#1}\mbox{$\displaystyle#2$}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\textnormal{Max}  \quad & R &\multialign{3}{{}=\log\left(...............\right)} \\
&\textnormal{s.t.} \quad & A &= B.C.D \quad&  E &= F.G.H \\
&&                         I &= J.K.L \quad&  M &= N.O.P
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It appears `\multicolumn` command must appear first in its cell. Your code (completed into a MWE) compiles with `{}\multicolumn` replaced by `\multicolumn` and the extra `\left` removed.

Comment: The problem with removing the `{}` is that the equals sign between R and log is no longer aligned with the equals signs between A & B and I & J. P.S. that extra `\left` was accidentally left from what was the contents. I will remove it now.

Comment: `\multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{}}{{}=\log\left(.....`

Answer (score 1):

It is not a direct answer to your question, but I would rather use the `align` environment in that case. The source code and output looks much cleaner to me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& \text{Max} & R& =\log\left(\dots\right)\\
& \text{s.t.}& A& = B.C.D & E &= F.G.H\\
&            & I& = J.K.L & M &= N.O.P
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Align]